# Create MySQL query with IDs from results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a a form which let's the user select what they want to display. Now the results of this looks like that: `9, 10, 11`. These are IDs from the table.

These are the IDs of the type they what to show. I have my query already, but I want to add this part at the end of my query.

So in this case:

```
$query = "type_ID = $result1 or type_ID = $result2 or type_ID = $result3"
```

if printed out with echo:

```
type_ID = 9 or type_ID = 10 or type_ID = 11
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried to loop and it,however this did not work and I am confused how to do add the MySQL code to this.

```
$result = $result . $_GET['type_ID'][$i]
```

Comment: Google mysql function `IN( ... )` I think that'll do what you want.

Comment: No sorry this is not what I'm looking for. I want that it add all the selected types to my $query. The $query will then be added to the whole query in order to display only the types that were selected. In the example above the types with the ID 9, 10 and 11 were selected. I did it manualy above, but obviously it should run on its own.

Comment: So, what is it you want us to help you with? - Get the ID's from GET?

Comment: No I want to create a query that selects only these types. I already have the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a tad unsure of what it is you are trying to achieve but from what I understand this should do it:

```
<?php
$tID = $_GET['type_ID'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE';

$i = 0;
foreach($tID AS $id){
    if($i == 0){
        $query .= ' type_ID = ' . $id;
        $i++;
    }else{
        $query .= ' OR type_ID = ' . $id;
    }
}
```

Although if you are only looking for the type_ID I'd still recommend using `IN()` like so:

```
<?php
$tID = $_GET['type_ID'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type_ID IN (" . implode(',',$tID) . ")";
```

In works just like OR, just instead of having to write multiple `OR` you can just use a single `IN()` :)

Comment: That looks good, I will try it later and write here again, many thanks.

Comment: @Alexis I was quite puzzled myself, although I figured I'd give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$query;
```

Comment: I already have my query, but the problem is the $query in your case. How can create the SQL for that, it should look like above.

Comment: if $query =" type_ID = 9 or type_ID = 10 or type_ID = 11"; and u've a column type_ID in you're table it's good...

Comment: Yes but these type IDs are selected everytime by the user. In this example the selected IDs were 9, 10 and 11. What whill happen if the user selects other types? It should for sure count them and run a for loop in my opinon.

Comment: You just need to change you're $query if the user select other types.

Comment: Yes but thats what i'm trying to achieve.